# Probability of winning a game in tennis?

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a tennis singles match, where Player A plays a single game against Player B.

The probability that player A will win a single point is $x$, and thus $1-x$ is the probability that Player B will win a point.

The scoring system in tennis goes 15, 30, 40, then game.  However a score of 40-40 is known as deuce and the winner of the next point gains an "advantage".  If this player wins again, he then wins the game, but if he loses the score returns to 40-40, or deuce.

So given the probability player A will win a single point is $x$, what is the probabilty that player A will win the entire game?

Comment: What was your approach, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @JiK, I have posted my attempt below, can you please check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [p chance of winning tennis point -> what f(p) chance of winning game?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44579/p-chance-of-winning-tennis-point-what-fp-chance-of-winning-game)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my attempt, I would appreciate feedback:

Let $p$ be the probability that player A wins a single point.

(1) Player A can win after 40-0, with probability $p^4$

(2)  Player A can win after 40-15 with probability ${4\choose 1}\times p^4(1-p)$

(3)  Player A can win after 40-30 with probability ${5\choose 2}\times p^4(1-p)^2$

(4) Player A can reach deuce, with probability ${6\choose 3}\times p^3(1-p)^3$, and once deuce is reached, player A will win with a probability of $\frac{p^2}{1-2p(1-p)}$ (http://www.austinrochford.com/posts/2013-04-25-probability-and-deuces-in-tennis.html)

Therefore the probability player A will win the game is given by,

$$P(Win) = p^4 + {4\choose 1}\cdot p^4(1-p) + {5\choose2}\cdot p^4(1-p)^2 + {6\choose 3}\cdot \frac{p^5(1-p)^3}{1-2p(1-p)}$$

Comment: The real problem is calculating the probability of winning after reaching deuce wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 2):

Numerically, this problem is easy using Markov chains. It is a little bit tricky to create the transition matrix. I will paste some R code I created just for fun.

```
transition_matrix <- function(p_win) {

    half_states <- c(0, 15, 30, 40)

    state <- function(own, opp) paste0(half_states[own], '/', half_states[opp])

    states <- c(state(expand.grid(1:4, 1:4)[, 1], expand.grid(1:4, 1:4)[, 2]), 'won', 'lost')

    tm <- array(0, dim = c(length(states), length(states)))

    colnames(tm) <- states
    rownames(tm) <- states

    rex <- '^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$'

    for (s in states) {
        if (grepl(rex, s)) {
            own <- which(half_states == gsub(rex, '\\1', s))
            opp <- which(half_states == gsub(rex, '\\2', s))

            stopifnot(length(own) == 1, length(opp) == 1)

            if (own < 4) {
                j_win <- which(states == state(own + 1, opp))
            } else {
                if (opp < 4) {
                    j_win <- which(states == 'won')
                } else {
                    j_win <- which(states == '40/30')
                }
            }
            if (opp < 4) {
                j_lost <- which(states == state(own, opp + 1))
            } else {
                if (own < 4) {
                    j_lost <- which(states == 'lost')
                } else {
                    j_lost <- which(states == '30/40')
                }
            }

            stopifnot(length(j_win) == 1, length(j_lost) == 1)

            i  <- which(rownames(tm) == s)

            tm[i, j_win]  <- p_win
            tm[i, j_lost] <- 1 - p_win

        } else {
            if (s == 'won') tm['won', 'won'] <- 1 else tm['lost', 'lost'] <- 1
        }
    }

    tm
}
```

For example, transition_matrix(0.3) is:

```
      0/0 15/0 30/0 40/0 0/15 15/15 30/15 40/15 0/30 15/30 30/30 40/30 0/40 15/40 30/40 40/40 won lost
0/0     0  0.3  0.0  0.0  0.7   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
15/0    0  0.0  0.3  0.0  0.0   0.7   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
30/0    0  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
40/0    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.7  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.3  0.0
0/15    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.3   0.0   0.0  0.7   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
15/15   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.3   0.0  0.0   0.7   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
30/15   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.3  0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
40/15   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.7  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.3  0.0
0/30    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.3   0.0   0.0  0.7   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
15/30   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.3   0.0  0.0   0.7   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.0
30/30   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.3  0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0 0.0  0.0
40/30   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.7 0.3  0.0
0/40    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.3   0.0   0.0 0.0  0.7
15/40   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.3   0.0 0.0  0.7
30/40   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.3 0.0  0.7
40/40   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.3  0.0   0.0   0.7   0.0 0.0  0.0
won     0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 1.0  0.0
lost    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0 0.0  1.0
>
```

Now, what you are looking for is the result after playing infinite points. For practical purposes, multiplying the matrix by itself 20 times is like playing 2^20 == 1,048,576 points. You can expect all paths to be either 'won' or 'lost' after that many points.

```
for (time in 1:20) tm <- tm %*% tm
```

And what you get is the probability of winning for each possible initial state,  not only 0/0.

```
> tm[1:16, c('won', 'lost')]
              won      lost
0/0   0.099211034 0.9007890
15/0  0.210981724 0.7890183
30/0  0.412168966 0.5878310
40/0  0.710224138 0.2897759
0/15  0.051309310 0.9486907
15/15 0.124758621 0.8752414
30/15 0.284431034 0.7155690
40/15 0.586034483 0.4139655
0/30  0.019831034 0.9801690
15/30 0.056327586 0.9436724
30/30 0.155172414 0.8448276
40/30 0.408620690 0.5913793
0/40  0.004189655 0.9958103
15/40 0.013965517 0.9860345
30/40 0.046551724 0.9534483
40/40 0.155172414 0.8448276
>
```

Additionally, you can solve the inverse problem using optimize()

```
sq_error <- function (p_win, p_win_game) {
    tm <- transition_matrix(p_win)

    for (time in 1:20) tm <- tm %*% tm

    (tm['0/0', 'won'] - p_win_game)^2
}

p_win <- optimize(function(p) sq_error(p, p_win_game = 0.3), c(0, 1))$minimum

> p_win
[1] 0.4166342
```