# Tennis related probability question

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Found this question quite puzzling, was hoping to get some help with it :).

> A tennis match is played as a series of POINTS, contained within
>   GAMES, which in turn are contained within SETS.
>
> If a player reaches 4 or more points won in a game, and also has won 2
>   points more than their opponent, then they win that game.
>
> If a player reaches 6 or more games won in a set, and also has won 2
>   games more than their opponent, then they win that set. If both
>   players reach 6 games, then a TIE-BREAK is played to determine the
>   winner of the set.
>
> Suppose Djokovic plays a set of tennis against Murray under these
>   rules, and his probablity of winning a point is 0.54. Assuming the
>   probability of winning a point remains constant throughout, what would
>   be the probability of Djokovic losing the set 2-6?

I'm struggling to figure out the probability of Djokovic winning a game, let alone a set. My thinking so far is you could add the probability of the case where he wins 4 points in a row, with the probability that he wins four and Murray gets one as well, then add the infinite amount of scenarios where Djokovic wins by 2 points which meant adding this:

$$
\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\binom{2n-2}{n}(0.45)^n(0.55)^{n-2}
\,
$$

That's when I realised I was way in over my head, grateful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is the probability of winning a point, then the probability of winning a game can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126327/probability-of-winning-a-game-in-tennis) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44579/p-chance-of-winning-tennis-point-what-fp-chance-of-winning-game) and is $$P_g = p^4 + {4\choose 1}\cdot p^4(1-p) + {5\choose2}\cdot p^4(1-p)^2 + {6\choose 3}\cdot \frac{p^5(1-p)^3}{1-2p(1-p)}$$

To win $2$ games and lose $6$ games can be done in ${7\choose 2}$ ways (the last game is always a loss), so the probability for that set score is $$P={7 \choose 2}\cdot P_g^2(1-P_g)^6$$