# 2 people play a tennis match. Probability of winning?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Players A and B play a tennis match that consists of 5 SETS. The probability of A winning the first set is 1/2.

If he wins this set, his probability of winning the next set remains 1/2. If he loses, his probability of winning the next set becomes 1/4.

If he wins now, the probability of winning the next one goes back up to 1/2, otherwise, it stays at 1/4.

What is the probability that A wins the MATCH?

**My attempt:**
I considered every possible configuration, like (WWW, WWLW, WLLWW....) and came to the answer 5/16, which is CORRECT.

I have two doubts:

1. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?
2. Surprisingly, if we were to just find the possible 5 letter permutations containing W and L, the ones containing 3 Ws are simply <sup>5</sup>C<sub>3</sub> and the total number of permutations are 2<sup>5</sup>.

Hence the probability of a random permutation to have 3 Ws is <sup>5</sup>C<sub>3</sub> / 2<sup>5</sup>.

Which is also 5/16! Does this have anything to do with anything?

**Note: This problem is not a duplicate, since whether the player wins/ loses, affects the probability of winning the next set.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [p chance of winning tennis point -> what f(p) chance of winning game?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44579/p-chance-of-winning-tennis-point-what-fp-chance-of-winning-game)

Comment: How so? In my problem, the probability of winning a set isn't constant. It changes depending on whether he loses/wins

Comment: This question doesn't mention Wii Tennis but that doesn't really change what the answers are going to be.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm unable to understand how that problem is related to mine. In that problem, it clearly states that there is a FIXED chance p of winning a point. 

Also, it also assumes that the game continues to the 5th point even after the winner is decided, while in my problem, it stops when one player wins 3 sets.

Comment: I would solve the problem by drawing the tree of the game and adding the probabilities of all game scenarios where $A$ wins; I don't think that your numerology is related to the problem.

Comment: That's how I solved it as well. i was wondering if there was an easier way and why a simple permutation gave me the same answer. Maybe it really has nothing to do with it.